# Showing testbox text in a label after clicking submit button in MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a testbox control and a submit button control in my form together with a label control. When i type in some text in my testbox control and click the button control i am not being able to display that text in my label control. Kindly help.

As i am new to MVC and am learning the basics it will be very helpful for me if you can kindly give me the full coding.

You can also kindly mail me the codings.  Thanks in advance.

My codes are as follows:

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

namespace TestMVCProj.Models

{
     public class TestPost
     {
      public string name {get; set;}
     }
}
```

Controller

```
using TestMVCProj.Models

public ActionResult TestPost(TestPost tp)
{
    return View();
}
```

View

```
@model TestMVCProj.Models.TestPost
@{
     ViewBag.Title ="TestPost";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.TestBoxFor (x => x.name)
     <input type="submit" />
}
Your Name is <%= Model.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the model to View when post.

```
public ActionResult TestPost(TestPost tp)
{
    return View(tp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need two actions in the Controller:

1. One that takes HTTP GET, and no parameters -- for the initial page load
2. One that takes HTTP POST, and the model as parameter -- for the postback

---

```
public ActionResult TestPost()
{
    return View();
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestPost(TestPost post)
{
    return View(post);
}
```

Also, since you're using Razor for the View, the syntax should be like this:

```
Your Name is @Model.name
```

Answer (score 0):

change your view to

```
 @model TestMVCProj.Models.TestPost
@{
     ViewBag.Title ="TestPost";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     Html.TextBoxFor (x => x.name)
     <input type="submit" />
}
Your Name is @Model.name
```